# Isotope: Resize elements before reLayout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to resize some elements, in the isotope grid.

I **dont** want this to happen each time window resizes.
I just want it before the reLayout function of isotope.

is there a way i can do this?
Any callback just before the reLayout?

Thanx!

Comment: Please post the code you are using to resize the elements.  I believe you'll need to resize the elements and then call reLayout as there doesn't seem to be an event prior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way.
I was already extending isotope with the Centered Masonry mode.
In the extended resize function, i made the resize changes on the isotope elements,
then triggered a resize(dont know for sure if this is a proper way), and that did the trick.

Now everytime isotope wants to reLayout, just before it, i resize the elements!

Here is the code:

```
$.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function () {

            //  Resize elements

            //Code that sets a new width for all elements

            // Force a relayout
            $('#container').isotope( 'reLayout');

            //Rest of the overriden method
            var prevColCount = this.masonry.cols;
            // get updated colCount
            this._getCenteredMasonryColumns();
            return ( this.masonry.cols !== prevColCount );
        };
```